# How do I define new guards in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I'm trying make an extra guard for Elixir that tests if a `Decimal` is zero.

I'm struggling; I'm not sure if should be use a defmacro, a defguard, both, or something else. What's the right approach (no need to submit a solution, even just the right idea would help).

```elixir
defmodule Decimal.Extended do
  @zero Decimal.new(0)
  defmacro zero?(x) do
    quote do
      Decimal.eq?(unquote(x),Decimal.new(0))
    end
  end
  # Kernel.defguard iszero?(x) when zero?(x)
end

defmodule Decimal.Ex.Test do
  require Decimal.Extended
  import Decimal.Extended
  def test(x) when zero?(x) do
    IO.inspect("zero")
  end

  def test(x) do
    IO.inspect("not zero")
  end
end
```

One such error:

```elixir
== Compilation error in file lib/helpers.ex ==
** (CompileError) lib/helpers.ex:20: cannot invoke remote function Decimal.new/1 inside guards
    expanding macro: Decimal.Extended.zero?/1
    lib/helpers.ex:20: Decimal.Ex.Test.test/1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One cannot invoke remote functions in guards. It’s explicitly stated in [`Kernel.defguard/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#defguard/1) docs:

> It raises at compile time if the definition uses expressions that aren’t allowed in guards, and otherwise creates a macro that can be used both inside or outside guards.

That said, only a subset of functions *and* their combinations are allowed. All the functions allowed in guards are marked with “allowed in guards” statement in the documentation (e. g. [`is_map/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#is_map/1).)

---

*Sidenote:* from the same docs:

> Note the convention in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) is to name functions/macros allowed in guards with the is_ prefix, such as `is_list/1`. If, however, the function/macro returns a boolean and is not allowed in guards, it should have no prefix and end with a question mark, such as `Keyword.keyword?/1`.

---

*Sidenote #2:* your particular need is guardable, though. `Decimal` is a [struct under the hood](https://github.com/ericmj/decimal/blob/v2.0.0/lib/decimal.ex#L104-L108), and the below would work:

```elixir
defguard is_zero(decimal) 
  when is_struct(decimal, Decimal) and
       decimal.coef === 0 and decimal.exp === 0
```